# How to develop a company.package2 with company.package1 dependency without namespace conflicts (python, pep 423)

Tags: python, namespaces, pypi, python-packaging, modulenotfounderror

I'm in the process of publishing several packages on pypi.  After doing some reading I like the idea of using a company.package naming convention to avoid namespace conflicts. (e.g. https://peps.python.org/pep-0423/#use-a-single-name, https://medium.com/@ashley.e.shultz/naming-company-python-packages-d1295fb9008d)

For instance (from medium article):

| import name | package name | distribution name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| acme.requests_utils | acme-requests-utils | acme-requests-utils |

Structure:

```
└── acme
    └── __init__.py
    └── request_utils
        └── __init__.py
```

This isn't a problem per say, but becomes a problem if I want to develop, debug, test, etc. another company package that has a company package as a dependency (installed by pip) in an IDE.

So for example working on: acme-webcrawer as an active development (e.g. a project within an IDE at pythonprojects/)

With a structure:

```
└── acme
    └── __init__.py
    └── webcrawler
        └── __init__.py
        └── crawler.py
```

if crawler.py has an import :

`from acme.request_utils import requester`

will yield an exception:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named acme.request_utils`

as the local folder "pythonprojects/acme" overrides the  "./site-packages/acme" folder

Once the package is published and installed via pip it's no problem as then everything in the site-packages/acme folder, but it makes it a real pain to fix bugs.

I must not be the first person to have this issue.  Is there a clever solution or am I being dumb (a real possibility), or doing something dumb that's just going to make my life harder?

FYI if it's important I use pycharm as my IDE.

I have considered using relative imports in my package, but this seems like a poor strategy

Comment: If `acme` is meant to be a "namespace package", then there should be no `__init__.py` in the `acme` directory in any of the distribution packages. https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/

Comment: This seems like the thing I, stupidly, missed... Thanks for pointing it out.  I'll dig into it!

Comment: For anyone who has the same... mental state... That I do.  imports are as expected `from acme.webcrawler.crawler import WebMuncher`.  For those using pycharm mark your src as root and mark the "acme" folder as namespace package and everything will work.